# Как пробросить Qualcomm WiFi адаптер в QEMU?

Tags: linux, wifi, взлом, termux

Возможно, мой вопрос покажется странным, но все же. Как пробросить внутренний WiFi адаптер (qcacvld3, устройство - jason (Xiaomi Mi Note 3)) в виртуалку QEMU? Читал немного про проброс PCI - как, например, видеокарты пробрасывали. Однако, `lspci` пуст:

```
rdice779@termux:~$ lspci
rdice779@termux:~$ tsu
root@termux:~# lspci
root@termux:~# su
root@android:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/root# lspci
```

есть ли вообще способы перевести из под виртуалки WiFi адаптер в режим монитора со всеми вытекающими? Конечно, можно пробросить внешний адаптер: `(qemu-command) -usb -usbdevice host:wifi-adapter`, либо нормально установить тот же **Nethunter** (или **Linux Deploy**), и из него заводить внутренний адаптер, но что-то не слишком охота ставить лишнее Linux-окружение. Из под Termux Wifite не заводится. Мб termux-chroot будет выходом, однако у меня чуть по другому висят файлы в Termux, `termux-chroot` если и получится без предварительной конфигурации, то через одно место.

Comment: Тебе сеть нужна? Ну так воспользуйся штатными инструментами. Хочешь поставить Кали Линукс, потому что посмотрел Мистера робота? Ну я бы начал с другого конца.

Comment: мне нужно заводить внутренний адаптер, т к не могу подкинуть внешний (разве что в виртуалка)+внешний адаптер не слишком удобно пробрасывать - громоздкий...

Comment: Т.е. ты хочешь сказать, что qemu **не** предоставляет виртуальный адаптер внутри гостевой системы, чтобы в виртуалке была сеть?

Comment: так внешний адаптер скорее всего usb - пробрось его по usb или по спайсу.

Comment: don Rumata, мне нужно пробросить сам внутренний адаптер Qualcomm, чтобы его переводить в режим монитора

Comment: Подозреваю, что в андроиде вы вряд ли его пробросите, скорее всего ядро просто собрано без нужных подсистем

Comment: я могу - из под Nethunter - перевести адаптер в режим монитора, без ядра